# DB2 Trigger to avoid duplicates

Tags: sql, database, db2

I am new to DB2. I had a task like, I have to write a trigger which should avoid duplicates while inserting data.

```
Table : Books 
Columns : book_id, book_name, author, copies
```

Wrote trigger like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tri_books_edit 
BEFORE INSERT ON books 
REFERENCING NEW AS N
FOR EACH ROW 
WHEN ((select count(*) from books where book_name = N.book_name and author = N.Author) > 0)
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '75000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Duplicate row with same name and author'
```

But, it is just sending error but my task is to insert data if the bookname and author is not present in DB else should not insert

Comment: Is this a homework assignment (ie, is doing this as a trigger mandatory)?  Otherwise, you'd be better served by making this a `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` instead.  There are potential problems with this database design - eg, you can't have multiple authors for the same book.

Comment: Hi..My real time scenario is similar to that. It was an example. Real time scenario is, if two batches executes same data parallel, we should not insert both batches data. This trigger should invoke before the insert and should check in DB and insert if data is not there ..

Comment: I'd still try to do this with a constraint - depending on the design of the trigger, it's still possible to get duplicate entries (in the case of two interleaved threads, you'd probably need to essentially lock the table).  It'd also be good to try and limit the possibility of duplicate batches.  Note that while anonymization may occasionally be appropriate, hiding essential parts of the problem (ie, potentially interleaved threads) may net you incorrect results.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Any keyword to skip the current row in DB2 trigger](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22608235/any-keyword-to-skip-the-current-row-in-db2-trigger)