# Any keyword to skip the current row in DB2 trigger

Tags: sql, database, db2

I have to write a trigger to insert the data into the DB if doesn't exists. 
       I wrote till inserting the records. I am doing signaling if the data is exists which 
       is failing my entire batch of records.

```
   My questions: Is there any keyword which will skip/ignore/discard the current row? 
   My trigger is below. I want to remove signal and keep something else which will 
   discard/ignore/skip the current row insertion. For example : Continue keyword in JAVA  .

   CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tri_books_edit 
   NO CASCADE BEFORE INSERT ON books 
   REFERENCING NEW AS N
   FOR EACH ROW 
   WHEN ((select count(*) from books where book_name = N.book_name and author = N.Author) > 0)
   SIGNAL SQLSTATE '75000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Duplicate row with same name and author' 

   Thanks for your help
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a trigger for this.  Just add a unique index on the two fields:

```
create unique index books_name_author on books(book_name, author);
```

Much simpler solution for preventing duplicates.

Comment: Great and thanks a lot Gordon !!! its worked for me. And also , is there any option to track the duplicates entries which are rejected. Please suggest me ...

Comment: @user3454735 . . . I don't actually know.  Many databases include logging or "return" features for `INSERT`, but I am not sure how DB2 does this.